# zend SMTP No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused

Tags: php, zend-framework

The snippet below:

```
$config = array('auth' => 'login',
                'username' => 'myusername',
                'password' => 'password');

$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('mail.server.com', $config);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText('This is the text of the mail.');
$mail->setFrom('sender@test.com', 'Some Sender');
$mail->addTo('recipient@test.com', 'Some Recipient');
$mail->setSubject('TestSubject');
$mail->send($transport);
```

...is throwing the following error:

```
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused."
```

What is the mistake in the snippet? I just took it from the zend framework online tutorial.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely it’s either wrong credentials or auth method, or the SMTP server is rejecting the connection based on IP or whatever. You should look into the documentation the owner of the SMTP server provides on how to connect to their server for delivering mails.

Comment: @CBroe unable to understand, urs comment, can u plz ref some exact thread or documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well try adding this to your configuration for SMTP

```
$config = array('auth' => 'login',
'username' => 'myusername',
'password' => 'password'
'ssl' => 'ssl',
'port' => $port
);
```

$port may vary according to the SMTP Provider generally its 465 but go through the SMTP service provider manual/help for correct port.

Hope this helps